# SQL Anywhere 11: Select brings inconsistent results when database cache is low

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

We have a complex sql query with five subquerys and the group by clause. If I restrict the database server cache to 16m (with the option "-ch 16m") we get randomized different results from the same sql query (these issue is reproducible on different machines). Our customer have the same issue on his system without reducing the cache with the -ch option and with 8g of free memory.

What is a possible explanation for such a behavior?

We think that it would be better to get a warning message or a database server crash than inconsistent results.

- DB-Version: 11.0.1.2744
- DB-Size: ~1g
- We tested it also with the newest 11.0.1.XXXX EBF release.

Here the sql:

```
SELECT (select year(beginnt) * 100 + month ( beginnt ) FROM geschaeftsjahr WHERE beginnt <= '2012-06-30' and 
 endet >= '2012-06-30' and 
 mandant_nr = i1_mandant_nr) geschaeftsjahresbeginn_vorjahr_yyyymm, 
(select beginnt from geschaeftsjahr where beginnt <= '2012-06-30' and 
 endet >= '2012-06-30' and 
 mandant_nr = i1_mandant_nr) geschaeftsjahresbeginn_vorjahr_datum, 
(select year(beginnt) * 100 + month ( beginnt ) from geschaeftsjahr where beginnt <= '2013-06-30' and 
 endet >= '2013-06-30' and 
 mandant_nr = i1_mandant_nr) geschaeftsjahresbeginn_yyyymm, 
(select beginnt from geschaeftsjahr where beginnt <= '2013-06-30' and 
 endet >= '2013-06-30' and 
 mandant_nr = i1_mandant_nr) geschaeftsjahresbeginn_datum, 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_kstnummer", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_bezeichnung", 
isnull(sum ( if ksb1_jahr*100+ksb1_monat >= year('2013-06-01')*100+month('2013-06-01') then if not isnull("bereich",'') = 'C' then "ksb1_betrag" else 0 endif else 0 endif * get_vorzeichen_kore(ksb1_mandant_nr, 
ksb1_kontonummer)) ,0) "betrag_kosten", 
isnull(sum ( if ksb1_jahr*100+ksb1_monat >= year('2013-06-01')*100+month('2013-06-01') then if isnull("bereich",'') = 'C' then "ksb1_betrag" else 0 endif else 0 endif * get_vorzeichen_kore(ksb1_mandant_nr, 
ksb1_kontonummer)) ,0) "betrag_ertrag", 
betrag_kosten + betrag_ertrag "betrag", 
isnull(sum ( if ksb1_jahr*100+ksb1_monat >= year('2013-06-01')*100+01 then if not isnull("bereich",'') = 'C' then "ksb1_betrag" else 0 endif else 0 endif * get_vorzeichen_kore(ksb1_mandant_nr, 
ksb1_kontonummer)) ,0) "betrag_kosten_jahresbeginn", 
isnull(sum ( if ksb1_jahr*100+ksb1_monat >= year('2013-06-01')*100+01 then if isnull("bereich",'') = 'C' then "ksb1_betrag" else 0 endif else 0 endif * get_vorzeichen_kore(ksb1_mandant_nr, 
ksb1_kontonummer)) ,0) "betrag_ertrag_jahresbeginn", 
betrag_kosten_jahresbeginn + betrag_ertrag_jahresbeginn "betrag_jahresbeginn", 
isnull(sum ( if not isnull("bereich",'') = 'C' then if isnull("ks1_kumulation",'g') = 'a' then /*seit auftragsbeginn*/ "ksb1_betrag" else /*seit Jahresbeginn*/ if ksb1_jahr*100+ksb1_monat >= year('2013-06-01')*100+01 then "ksb1_betrag" else 0 endif endif else 0 endif * get_vorzeichen_kore(ksb1_mandant_nr, 
ksb1_kontonummer)) ,0) "betrag_kosten_baubeginn", 
isnull(sum ( if isnull("bereich",'') = 'C' then if isnull("ks1_kumulation",'g') = 'a' then /*seit auftragsbeginn*/ "ksb1_betrag" else /*nur Vorjahreszahlen*/ if ksb1_jahr*100+ksb1_monat >= year('2013-06-01')*100+01 then "ksb1_betrag" else 0 endif endif else 0 endif * get_vorzeichen_kore(ksb1_mandant_nr, 
ksb1_kontonummer)) ,0) "betrag_ertrag_baubeginn", 
betrag_kosten_baubeginn + betrag_ertrag_baubeginn "betrag_baubeginn", 
isnull(sum ( "ksb1_betrag" ),0) "betrag_vorjahr", 
count() count, 
"i_daten"."i1_name", 
"i_daten"."i1_mandant_nr", 
"i_daten"."i1f1_zahlenformat_auswertung", 
isnull(v_kostenstellenplan.ks1_inaktiv, 
'n' ) kst_inaktiv, 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr1", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez1", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez_ergebnis1", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr2", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez2", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez_ergebnis2", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr3", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez3", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez_ergebnis3", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr4", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez4", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez_ergebnis4", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nrn", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_typ", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_kumulation", 
isnull((select k.ks1_verantwortlicher from kostenstelle k where k.ks1_kstnummer = "v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_kstnummer" and 
 k.ks1_mandant_nr = "v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_mandant_nr"),'') kst_verantwortlicher FROM "v_kostenstellenplan" join "konto_kst_statistik_budget" on "v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_mandant_nr" = "konto_kst_statistik_budget"."ksb1_mandant_nr" and 
 "v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_kstnummer" = "konto_kst_statistik_budget"."ksb1_kostenstelle" and 
 "v_kostenstellenplan"."kl1_typ" = 'ks2' join "konto" on "konto"."kontonummer" = "konto_kst_statistik_budget"."ksb1_kontonummer" and 
 "konto"."mandant_nr" = "konto_kst_statistik_budget"."ksb1_mandant_nr" join "i_daten" on "konto"."mandant_nr" = "i_daten"."i1_mandant_nr" where not ksb1_quelle = string(char(70), 
char(51)) and 
 not "left"(ksb1_quelle,1) = CHAR(66) and 
 string('D1;D2;D3;F1;F2;F4;F5;F50;F51;F52;K1;K2;L1;N1;N2;N3;N4;N5;O1;O2;P1;', 
'F20;F21;F23;') like string(char(37),ksb1_quelle, 
char(59) , 
char(37)) and 
 /*Seit Baubeginn oder Geschäftsjahresbeginn*/ ksb1_jahr*100+ksb1_monat >= if isnull("v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_kumulation",'g') = 'a' then 0 else year('2012-06-01')*100+month('2012-06-01') end if and 
 ksb1_jahr*100+ksb1_monat <= year('2013-06-30')*100+month('2013-06-30') and
 "kontonummer" not in (907010,997010,907011,997011 ) and 
 ks1_kstnummer in (select kk.kk1_kostenstelle from kostenstelle_Klassierung kk join klassierung_typ on kk1_typ = kt1_typ join klassierung on kl1_id = kk1_klassierung_id where kk1_mandant_nr = isnull(i1_kostenstellen_vererben_von_mandant_nr, 
i1_mandant_nr) and 
 kk1_typ = 'kst' and 
 kl1_nummer >= '7150' and 
 kl1_nummer <= '7150' ) and 
 i1_mandant_nr in (13) GROUP BY "v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_kstnummer", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_bezeichnung", 
"i_daten"."i1_name", 
"i_daten"."i1_mandant_nr", 
"i_daten"."i1f1_zahlenformat_auswertung", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_inaktiv", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr1", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez1", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez_ergebnis1", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr2", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez2", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez_ergebnis2", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr3", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez3", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez_ergebnis3", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr4", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez4", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_bez_ergebnis4", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nrn", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_typ", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."ks1_kumulation", 
ks1_mandant_nr HAVING ( "betrag_kosten" <> 0 OR "betrag_ertrag" <> 0 OR "betrag" <> 0 OR "betrag_kosten_jahresbeginn" <> 0 OR "betrag_ertrag_jahresbeginn" <> 0 OR "betrag_jahresbeginn" <> 0 OR "betrag_kosten_baubeginn" <> 0 OR "betrag_ertrag_baubeginn" <> 0 ) ORDER BY i_daten.i1_mandant_nr, 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr1", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr2",
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr3", 
"v_kostenstellenplan"."kl_nr4", 
"ks1_kstnummer"
```

The column "betrag_kosten" for example delivers different results (see the printscreen).

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the results are different or that the results are the same but in a different order?

Comment: Please post the query itself. Perhaps that will give someone an idea as to where the problem lies.

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn - The results are different, the order is correct.

Comment: @GraemePerrow - I have added the original sql and a printscreen of the different results.

Comment: I was hoping the SQL would indicate the problem but I'm afraid it doesn't tell me anything. Then again I'm not on the query execution team. You may consider posting your question to sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com, where SQL Anywhere experts and engineers may be able to help you.

Comment: You may want to open a ticket with SAP on this, it could be a bug.